# How to fetch a number ending with a specific digit in linux

Tags: linux

I have a file somewhat like :
Hello, World!
Name Age Place
Abc  26  CO
Def  27  CA
Ghi  45  MH
Jkl  32  SD

How to find the line in which Age ends with 2?
Output I am expecting is - Jkl  32  SD

Comment: Can you provide further informations. you need a bash script for that ?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to do this with `GREP` utility, using the `-n` option, which will prefix each line of output with the line number of the input file.

If this is your input file:

```
Hello, World!
Name Age Place
Abc 26 CO
Def 27 CA
Ghi 45 MH
Jkl 32 SD
```

Then:

```
$ grep -n "2 " inputFile.text
6: Jkl 32 SD
```

Here you can see that the pattern you are looking for can be found on line 6.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to do that in bash script :

```
#!/bin/bash
input="/path/to/file"
while IFS= read -r line
do
  echo "$line" | grep  '2'
done < "$input"
```

Comment: Why you need to iterate over each line? grep already does that. And it already prints. Your solution will output every line that has a 2 on it.

Comment: yes totally, i forgot about the condition

Comment: Your bash script can be simplified to `grep '2' /path/to/file`

Answer (score 0):

A quick and hacky way would be to use grep.

For your use case, I would try `grep -E '\s[0-9]*2\s' infile > outfile`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your file is named saa:

```
awk '{if(match($2,/2$/)){print}}' saa
Jkl 32 SD
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 grep -E '^.*[[:space:]][[:digit:]]?2[[:space:]].*$' file
```

Enable regular expression interpretation in grep (-E) Search for the start of the line followed by "anything", then a space, zero or more digits, a two, a space, "anything" and the end of the line.

Answer (score -1):

try with grep:

grep '[2]$' inputfile > outputfile

cheers!

Comment: It does not gonna work from what I see, please elaborate why you think it's correct?